# MYSQL query using variable as table name in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

```
SELECT var1,var2,var3,table_name 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table_name on var3=table_name.id
```

Meaning I want to dynamically left join table, depending on value of `table_name` from `table1`, since `var3` is taken from there.

But the above query results in

> table table_name does not exist

My mistake of mysql limitation?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. You will likely need to pass the table name in to a stored procedure if you want this type of functionality or redesign what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's not a MySQL limitation. More like SQL limitation if you can call it that, but I wuold rather say, it's an indication that something's wrong with your database design.

Comment: Main table contains objects. Each object can have attributes. There are separate tables for each attribute listing possible values - values can be very long (several hundred chars) and there are many possible values (thousands).

So the main table has 2 fields per attribute: attr_table_name, attr_table_id - to save space and to allow attribute name modification.

When query is run, I return actual attribute value, not the id, thats why I need LEFT JOIN and dynamic table naming.

How else would you design the DB?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Table names, as well as column names, can't be dynamic in an SQL query. So you have to apply your logic programmatically, using 2 queries, or with a stored procedure, see an example here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,126506,126598#msg-126598

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to unite all tables with a [union query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51134719/3423324):

```
SELECT *, 44 as table_origin FROM `Table_44`
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 58 as table_origin FROM `Table_58`;
```

You could even prepare that as view:

```
CREATE VIEW `AllTheTables` AS
SELECT *, 42 as table_origin FROM `Table_42`
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 44 as table_origin FROM `Table_44`
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 58 as table_origin FROM `Table_58`
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 69 as table_origin FROM `Table_69`;
```

And thus query it safely:

```
SELECT * FROM AllTheTables WHERE table_origin IN (44,58) AND something = 'foobar';
-- or --
SELECT * FROM AllTheTables WHERE table_origin = 42 AND something = 'the question';
```

---

In your exact case it could look like this:

```
SELECT var1, var2, var3, table_name 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN AllTheTables ON table1.var3=AllTheTables.table_origin
```