# Find table name & then get data from that table.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

`Model`

```
   ID     Model
    1      1
    2      2
    3      4
    4      10
```

`Model-table`

```
ID  model_id   table_name
1     1          table1
2     3          table2
3     4          table3
```

Note: It is not important that every model requires table_name.

I find the table_name of model width id 3, it is `table2`. It is so simple fo find it, I do not see the reason to write here my sql. After finding `table2`, I should select from `table2` and find all parametres. In this case I should write second sql. Here is the structure of `table2`

Note: We can find all parametres of model_id with 3.

`table2`

```
ID    model_id   param1      param2     param3
1          3        0           5          10
```

My question:
I am looking for the way, firstly find suitable model_id in `model_table` and fetch `table_name`, THEN SELECT from `table_name` and fetch all parametres with 1 SQL.

Note: I have id and model_id variables on my PHP PAGE. So, we need to use Limit 1 and fetch suitable data to 1 id and model_id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL query using variable as table name in LEFT JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646412/mysql-query-using-variable-as-table-name-in-left-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this in two queries as table names cannot be dynamic. Your code should look something like this:

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi(/*connection details*/);

// Fetch table name
$query = "SELECT table_name 
    FROM model-table 
    WHERE model_id = 3";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc($result);
$table = $row['table_name'];

// Fetch data from table2
$query = "SELECT ID, model_id, param1, param2, param3 
    FROM $table";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $mysqli->fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // do something with the data from the table...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really what you are looking for, but this can help you too

Find [all the tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html) of a database

```
SHOW TABLES
```

Find [all the columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/describe.html) of a table

```
DESCRIBE table_name
```