# Use the results of a query, such as another table_name

Tags: mysql

can I use the result of query (Query 1) as a table name into anothers query?
Example.
Query 1.

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE' AND 
table_schema='schemaName' AND table_name LIKE '%_assoc_device'
```

I would like to use every single query just written, like table name, to build new queries.

```
SELECT * FROM (Query 1 Result)
```

This query for each result.
With this automatic method, I would like to create a view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3646442/6124528

Comment: The solution is mySQL function?

Comment: I Try to use this set of command, but must limit the result to 1

SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT *
                                     FROM ', (SELECT table_name
          FROM information_schema.tables
                 WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE' AND                           table_schema='schemaName' AND table_name LIKE '%_assoc_device' LIMIT 1));
PREPARE s FROM @sql;                         
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

Answer (score 0):

I Try to use this set of command, but must limit the result to 1

```
SET @sql := CONCAT(
'SELECT * 
 FROM ', (SELECT table_name 
         FROM information_schema.tables 
         WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE' 
         AND table_schema='schemaName'
         AND table_name LIKE '%_assoc_device' LIMIT 1)
 );
 PREPARE s FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE s;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

Can I Extends this concept, to all result of subquery?